# rescuing multiple exception of the same type in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

Imagine this scenario (just a sample)

```
file = open("/file1")
file2 = open("/file2")
file3 = open("/file3")
```

How can i handle this situation, what i want to do is allow statements that don't rise exception run while catching any exception that they might rise, In other words i have 3 lines that can rise the same exception, how should this be handled. i can check the msg, but still if the first line throws an exception the next two lines won't run.

a relating question is can i have a nesting rescue blocks (meaning throw and rescue an exception inside a rescue block?)

Answer (score 1):

You might want a loop for this specific case:

```
open_files = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'].map do |file|
  begin
    File.open file
  rescue => e
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, figured it out.
not the smartest question!
just have each one in different method and call them.

```
Loadfile1()
Loadfile2()
Loadfile3()

loadfile1()
file1 = open("/file1")
rescue......
...
end
```